# Asp.Net Mvc Form does not post?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, drop-down-menu

view

```
@model Osos12Mvc3.Models.TblSayaclar
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="div_dialog_container" class="dialog_container">
@using (Html.BeginForm((string)ViewBag.FormAction, "Sayac"))
{
    <div id="div_iu_form_container" class="ui_form_container">
        <div>@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Sayaç Kaydı Başarısız! Lütfen Bilgileri Kontrol Ediniz.")
        </div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2">
                        Genel Bilgiler
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.LabelFor(x => x.TblMusteriler.musteri_adi):
                    </td>
                    <td>@Html.DropDownList("sno", (SelectList)ViewBag.musteri_id, "--Müşteri Seçiniz--")
                    </td>
                     </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
        <table class="table_ui_buttons">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2">
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" value="Kaydet" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    }
 </div>
```

controller

```
public ActionResult SayacEkle()
{
    var musteriler = entity.TblMusteriler.Select(x => new { x.sno, x.musteri_adi });
    ViewBag.musteri_id = new SelectList(musteriler.AsEnumerable(), "sno", "musteri_adi");

    return ContextDependentView(new TblSayaclar());
}
```

Im using validationsummary in my view. When I clicked submit dropdownlist color change to red. (like required field). I dont understand that state. I debugged post event, It did not posted. Post action was not firing.

This is the Html Source:

```
<select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field sno must be a number." data-val-required="The sno field is required." id="sno" name="sno" class="input-validation-error"><option value="">--Müşteri Seçiniz--</option>
```

AliRıza Adıyahşi

What is the wrong?

Thanks

Comment: If the validation was fired (the dropdownlist are red as you're saying) that would prevent the post. Try posting with all your form fields correctly populated and set a breakpoint in your `SayaEkle` controller action and see if it hits that method before assuming it doesn't post

Comment: Should I change the sno type guid to int in my database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I clicked submit dropdownlist color change to red. (

If your view model property is marked with the Required attribute then it is normal that it gets validated:

```
[Required]
public string Sno { get; set; }
```

There are 2 levels of validation which run in that order:

1. Client side validation (not enabled by default, implement with jquery ubnobtrusive => prevent the form from being submitted)
2. Server side validation

If you are using client side validation (unobtrusive javascript) and you have a model error then the form will not even be posted to the server. The user needs to first fix his errors before being able to submit the form.

Comment: Then it is a non nullable integer, like this: `public int Sno { get; set; }`? If this is the case the Required attribute is implicitly added because it doesn't make any sense to map a non-nullable type such as Integer to a dropdown field which could have null values.

Comment: my model : `public partial class TblMusteriler
    {
        public TblMusteriler()
        {
            this.TblSayaclar = new HashSet<TblSayaclar>();
        }
    
        public System.Guid sno { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Müşteri No")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Müşteri numarası boş geçilemez.")]
        public string musteri_no { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Müşteri Adı")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Müşteri adı boş geçilemez.")]
        public string musteri_adi { get; set; }`

Comment: Ah there you go: your Sno property is of type `Guid`. Guid is a value type. So the Required attribute is automatically added by the framework. If you want to manage a default empty value in your dropdown you need to use a nullable Guid type on your model, like this: `public System.Guid? sno { get; set; }`. If not you will have to remove the default value from the dropdown: `"--Müşteri Seçiniz--"`.

Comment: Try submitting it with something selected and see if it hits your controller action

Comment: I submitting it with something selected, but It does not hit.

Comment: I added html source to question content. Could you look again the my question.

Comment: You should either remove the default option `"--Müşteri Seçiniz--"` or use a nullable Guid on your model depending on what you are trying to achieve and whether you want to allow for empty selection in this dropdown.